# I have created separate teams under one project. Is it possible to have different customized fields for the different teams within the project?

Tags: azure-devops, process

Our team have created new teams under one project. For example we have a project called 2021 and then various teams under this i.e. Q1, Q2, Q3 etc. I have created new teams in 'project settings' --> 'Teams'. **But, we would like to be able to customise and have different fields for each team as they may require different information.**

I have tried editing the process but cannot seem to do this and cannot seem to make different layouts under the work item types in the process for the project.

Any advice on how we can have separate layouts for different teams under one project would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

[created new teams](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRcH7.png)

Comment: You can't. If you need different customizations for work items, then you need to have different process templates under different team projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each project is based on a process that defines the building blocks for tracking work. You can only customize inherited processes. Any changes you make to the inherited process automatically appears in the **projects** that use that process. They can not apply on a particular team.

You may specify or give an example to describe how you want to different customized fields for the different teams, so that we can see whether there is any workaround.